# Java program is compiling in netbeans but not in CMD, package does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, javac, executable-jar

I'm working on a shop management System program. Building this using NetBeans, Java and SQL Server. I used a `Jdatepicker` in my Program. It is working well in NetBeans, but now I was trying to compile it through CMD. i'm using correct syntax, but yet it is giving me errors `package org.jdesktop.swingx does not exist
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;` with many similar errors about `datepicker`. I have already imported 4 libearies

```
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.CalendarHeaderHandler;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler;
```

for this purpose, It is working well in NetBeans but not in cmd. I have used `javac` in cmd using `-classpath file address.jar`, but same error occurred.
kindly assist me in this problem [Error image in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sKTU.png)

Comment: Are you including the necessary library jar files with your own jar file? Have you checked the class-path in the jar's manifest file, and that it includes a path to the additional jar files?

Comment: *i'm using correct syntax, but yet it is giving me errors*: then maybe you're not. How about telling us which precise command you're executing, and where the jar files are located?

Comment: JB Nizet! I have added them in my NetBeans Project in Libraries folder. Commands are as "javac PesticidesShop.java" and other one with classpath was as "javac -classpath E\CS\PestisidesShop\jdatepicker-1.3.4.jar PesticidesShop.java "

Comment: You need to create a "fat" jar. A fat jar includes all external dependencies in your application's jar. By default this does not happen. Idk if ur using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle, but you need to manually configure your build tool to include those other jars INSIDE of your jar. Also, idk how bcuz i dont use netbeans, but u can find the exact command netbeans uses and copy, paste, and run that from CMD

Comment: Ah. So you're not trying to **run** your code, but you're trying to **compile** it. Is that right? Assuming jdatepicker is the only library you depend on, and assuming it doesn't depend on any other library, the command should be `javac -classpath E:\CS\PestisidesShop\jdatepicker-1.3.4.jar PesticidesShop.java`. Note the `:` after the drive letter E. Write all the relevant information in your question, not in comments.

Comment: Thanks Nizet! I want to compile and then run it as it runs in NetBeans. But when it is giving error in compiling how I can write next line of `java PesticidesShop` only? Have a look at image that I had added in question

Comment: My guess is that your classpath is wrong: your project is in C:\Hamza\PesticidesShop, but your classpath uses E:\CS\PestisidesShop (note the typo, BTW). What is the output of the command `jar tvf E:\CS\PestisidesShop\jdatepicker-1.3.4.jar`?

Comment: I looked on google for `github org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker` ; seems like you are missing the `swingx-core` jar. It can be downloaded from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs.swingx/swingx-core/1.6.4 . Note that you will probably be missing other dependencies.

Comment: In order to compile from the command line, you will probably be better by creating a Maven project for your code; so that you can include the required jars as `dependencies`, and you may then build from the command line using `mvn package`. Your problem is due to missing dependencies- and maven solves that problem for you

Comment: NetBeans uses **ant** to compile projects. After building a project in NetBeans look in the project's **Output** window. The very first line is the **ant** command it used to build the project, so emulate NetBeans and using **ant** to build the project from the cmd line.

Comment: Also, for non-web projects the command you can use to run the project from the command line is also shown near the end of the output in the **Output** window. Here's a simple example: _"To run this application from the command line without Ant, try: C:\Java\jdk-10/bin/java -cp D:\NBRC1\JavaApplication2\dist\JavaApplication2.jar javaapplication2.JavaApplication2"_